# Workbook.CheckIn always produces an error the first time it's called?

Tags: vba, excel, sharepoint-2007

I have some workbooks stored in a document library on Sharepoint 2007.  I want to check out a workbook, modify it, and check it back in.

Using the following code:

```
Option Explicit

Public Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)

Sub test()

Dim bk As Workbook
Dim path As String

path = "http://sharepoint/sites/test/TEST_Relink.xlsm"

If Workbooks.CanCheckOut(path) Then
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Workbooks.CheckOut path
    DoEvents
    Set bk = Workbooks.Open(path, False)
    bk.Sheets("test").Range("h1").Value = "modified " & Now
    DoEvents
    Sleep 10000
    bk.checkIn True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End If


End Sub
```

The `bk.checkIn` call always produces the following run-time error:

```
Method 'CheckIn' of object '_Workbook' failed
```

After I go into Debug, I press `F5` to continue and the check-in always occurs successfully.

I added the 10-second delay with `Sleep 10000` because I was thinking that maybe the check-out was taking a while to propagate to the server.  But no matter how much time I set for `Sleep`, this same issue keeps occurring.  Any thoughts?

EDIT:

I tried using a looped check of `.CanCheckIn` as follows:

```
While Not bk.CanCheckIn
DoEvents
Wend
bk.checkIn True
```

This gave the same error.

Comment: try using [CanCheckIn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa223808(v=office.11).aspx), [CanCheckOut](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa223809(v=office.11).aspx) ( maybe also wrapping a time loop with a number of attempts around these checks if necessary )

Comment: @amdixon, this gave me the same error (see edit).

Answer (score 2):

For those finding this like I did, I had

```
Workbooks(logFileName).CheckIn SaveChanges:=True, Comments:="New row added from " & mainFile
```

This produced the error message like yours, however on entering debug and pressing f5 would action. So here is my complex solution.....I just split out the code to the following

```
Workbooks(logFileName).Save
Workbooks(logFileName).CheckIn Comments:="New row added from " & mainFile
```

Hope this helps others.

Comment: Calling `.Save` before `.CheckIn` worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
Dim xl As Excel.Application
Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xl.AutomationSecurity = msoAutomationSecurityForceDisable
xl.EnableEvents = False
xl.DisplayAlerts = False

'code to checkin/checkout

xl.EnableEvents = True
xl.DisplayAlerts = True
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably already figured it out but I thought I'd post it for anyone else who comes here looking for an answer.

If you are setting `SaveChanges` to `True` then you MUST also set `Comments` to be a String (a null value won't do)

So in your example you would need to do this:

`bk.CheckIn True, ""`